# I have a two columns that need editing on a large scale. mysql update statement

Tags: mysql

So I have two columns and the first is order_id and the second is affiliate id.

All my order id's listed below have an an affiliate id of 107. If they are on the list below I would like to mass update them to 103..

200000343
200000342
200000340
200000339
200000338
200000333
200000332
200000331
200000330
200000329
200000328

I hope that makes sense and it seems fairly easy but i'm not the best with mysql.

Would i just do something like this:

```
UPDATE affiliate_id 
   SET affiliate_id = IF(affiliate_id IS 107 ? 103)
 WHERE id = 200000343,
200000342,
200000340,
200000339,
200000338,
200000333,
200000332,
200000331,
200000330,
200000329,
200000328,
```

Comment: What are you intending with the `IF`? Do you want to change all rows having id `107` to `103`?

Comment: Please clarify - is the list of order ids shown here _all_ of the affiliate id = 107, or are there others for affiliate 107 that you do not want updated?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: the list of order id's shown here are all affiliate id = 107 and they need to be changed to 103. yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE affiliate_id 
SET affiliate_id = 103
WHERE affiliate_id = 107 AND id IN(200000343,
200000342,
200000340,
200000339,
200000338,
200000333,
200000332,
200000331,
200000330,
200000329,
200000328)
```

I'm assuming that your table is really called `affiliate_id` as well, if not, you have to put the right table name after `UPDATE`.

Comment: Given the latest comments, it isn't necessary to have the `IN()` list at all.

Comment: `WHERE affiliate_id = 107` is all that's needed.

Comment: oh.. i'm sorry i might of got confused.. there is other affiliate id's in the table that do not need to be updated.. only the order id's in the list need to be updated.

Comment: Okay, you need the `IN()` enumeration then.